# What happens before system starts to run main()?

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on embedded systems as beginner and have come across files like `start.s` or `cstart` files that run before main() function begins. What is the purpose of these or similar files? What information we are telling to the system?

Comment: Have you read those files? Wht in the contents don't you specifically understand? Did you read the datasheet of your architecture? The toolchain documentation? Stepped through the code with a debugger? Yes, you hardly can avoid that if you want to learn.

Comment: [This may be of interest](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237740/what-resides-in-the-different-memory-types-of-a-microcontroller).

Answer (score 8):

At close bare minimum, startup code before main() sets up "C environment": it initializes stack pointer, copies initialized variable values (.data) from non-volatile memory to RAM, and sets all uninitialized variables (.bss) to zero.

Depending on architecture, you may need to do something more. You may need to initialize clocking and/or other crucial peripherals, interrupt vectors, possibly set up processor contexts, and so on, before going to main() to continue system bootup.

Comment: ... this code usually sets up `argc` and `argv` as well.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker argc argv on an embedded system? What kind of weird system is that?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the architecture but typically it sets all non-initialized global variables to zero and sets up the stack pointer.